# How can I stream videos using VLC via RTSP in command line, as the root user?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cloud, vlc

I have a cloud computer which I can access through SSH. I login to my cloud pc as root.

I installed VLC media player application with apt-get command some time, however when I write "vlc" to the terminal I have the following output:

```
root@fercis:~# vlc
The program 'vlc' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
apt-get install vlc-nox
```

When I write "apt-get install vlc-nox" or "apt-get install vlc", the computer prints that I already have vlc installed:

```
root@fercis:~# apt-get install vlc-nox
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
vlc-nox is already the newest version.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-3.2.0-23-generic linux-headers-3.2.0-23 icedtea-netx
  icedtea-netx-common
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 167 not upgraded.
root@fercis:~# apt-get install vlc
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
vlc is already the newest version.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-3.2.0-23-generic linux-headers-3.2.0-23 icedtea-netx
  icedtea-netx-common
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 167 not upgraded.
```

Is there a problem in using VLC player as root in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

Type cvlc, or use vlc on a non root account. You could also use vlc-wrapper, from an account that is sudoed.